# I want to add react devtools to Safari browser

Tags: reactjs, safari-extension, safari-web-inspector

I want to add react devtools to Safari browser
I didn't find a way to install it

I want to see the react sign on the websites made by react

Thank you

Comment: look https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/67

Comment: Thank you a lot but I didn't find an answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the [react-devtools chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en)?
[React-devtools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-devtools) is a standalone package that runs independently.
The chrome extension hooks it up for convenience in chrome.

Safari doesn't have an extension right now (legacy reasons).
If you really need to hook it up, it should not be hard to port it to safari since it's API's are now supposedly as open and similar as chrome's.

Comment: Use this: https://github.com/seidnerj/react-devtools-in-safari-2023

Answer (score 4):

Starting with MacOS 13.0 Ventura and Safari 16.1, developers can now build and distribute Extensions for Safari Web Inspector, just like they do with Safari as a whole through the App Store.

It is now hopefully a matter of time before Facebook or someone else builds and distributes React Dev Tools for Safari.

[Reference: Adding a web development tool to Safari Web Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/creating_safari_web_inspector_extensions)

Comment: First effort: https://github.com/fycdev/react-devtools-in-safari-2022

Comment: Second effort: https://github.com/seidnerj/react-devtools-in-safari-2023